# Jenkins Continuous integration for iOS. Can I run pod install each time when my build job executes

Tags: ios, jenkins

I want to make sure the build job which is executed by Jenkins, has the latest pod libraries. I could not find any CocoaPods specific build step in jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

Open --> configure

Then --> pre-build steps

Then --> Execute Shell

Over here. You can first add the path to your podfile and then the *pod install* command.

Hope it helps.